# vim -c issue with %s, getting "Illegal variable name" error

Tags: vim

I want to perform the below steps on a vim file , but don’t want to do that manually.
I tried using the -c option but getting some error there.

Error which I get
vim file2 -c ":%s/$/|/g" -c ":wq"
Illegal variable name.

What is the error I'am making here ?

Once the above step is done, i want to remove the last  | from the file, is there some way for that as well through -c option only?

Regards

Comment: I don't understand the question exactly. Try to clarify what do you want to do first, than try to separate the command you used and the error you get.
For me 
vim file2 -c ":%s/$/|/g" -c ":wq"
works. But this adds | to the end of each lines. If you want to remove, you should use ":%s/|$//g" instead.

Comment: typing
vim file2 -c ":%s/$/|/g" -c ":wq"
in a command promt (not inside vim) work for me too.
Removing the last character of a file can be done with G$x